# How can I use dynamically generated routes with Nginx?

Tags: html, nginx

This would be solved easily using Apache and `.htaccess`.

My build system generates static HTML files which use JS for routing. I want Nginx to load different HTML files based on a set of rules. Since the rules are generated dynamically, it would be hacky to modify Nginx config files and reload Nginx every time I need to build.

I.e. the static HTML files and the build system are both in `/var/www`. Nginx is in `/etc/nginx`. I don't want the build system to modify `/etc/nginx`. Is there a way to have dynamic routing without modifying `/etc/nginx` and without reloading Nginx?

Ideally, I can output a JSON file in `/var/www` that looks something like:

```
[
  ['^/module1(/.+)?', 'module1.html'],
  ['^/module2/page', 'module2-page.html'],
  ['^/module2(/.+)', 'module2.html']
]
```

Comment: It's easy in Apache how? It's not possible in NGINX. But you can have a look at Nginx Unit which has API that you can leverage in order to dynamically update configuration on the fly (sure enough you have to write the code to parse your JSON and talk to the API)

Comment: In Apache, I can use `.htaccess` in `/var/www`

Comment: Since you control the output format. Then you can write an NGINX configuration file then `include` it from a `server {}` defined somewhere in `/etc/nginx`. You can place the included file anywhere you want, including `/var/www/custom.conf`